# Column collision in Left join with many columns vs PHPMyAdmin resultset

Tags: mysql, query, php, phpmyadmin

I have 4 tables (75 columns each table approx) but they share columns with the same name:

*Table Master_Producto*

```
Master_Product.PD_Prof_21
```

*Table Product_Structure*

```
Product_Structure.PD_Prof_21
```

I am doing left join; what happens is that when it bring them to the backend (php) they are overwritten ... expected 2 PD_Prof_21 but in php only one is retrive.

based on this solution (which does not solve my scenario, becouse i have around 300 columns) https://stackoverflow.com/a/10530252/4717133

I'm not convinced by the idea of using aliases with more than 300 columns ...
I know that the aliases in the columns would be something like:

```
SELECT Columns as column1 ... // this would be very heavy to do for each column ...
```

This other option, does not separate the tables in the resultset

```
SELECT 
Master_Product.*,
Product_Structure.*,
Supplier_Product.*,
Product_Price.*,
```

or at least in php I have problems, it turns out that of the 300 columns I only receive those that are not repeated, if a column is repeated, it only shows me the last one with the last value.

***First Doubt***

So I was wondering if there is any method in mysql that allows adding a prefix automatically to all columns in a resultset query, an example:

```
SELECT PREFIX ('Master_', Master_Product. *), PREFIX ('Structure_', Product_Structure. *) ...
```

and in PHP access to:

```
Master_PD_Prof_21
Structure_PD_Prof_21
```

***PHP script used to retrieve the information:***

**Connections**

```
function Open_Con_DB2($dbUsing) {
        $dblink = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASS, DB_PRE . $dbUsing);
        
        if ($dblink) {
            $dblink->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); # Enlace de Coneccion UTF-8
            return $dblink;
        } else {
            #No conviene mostrar errores internos
            #Cámbialos por mensajes personalizados en producción
            die( 'Error de Conexión ('
                 .mysqli_connect_errno(). ') '
                 . mysqli_connect_error()
                );
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Get Information.**

```
function BDquery2($dbquery, $dbUsing) {
        $dblink = $this->Open_Con_DB2($dbUsing);
        if ($dblink) {
            if ( $datos = mysqli_query($dblink, $dbquery) ) {
                $outPut=array();
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos)) {
                    $outPut[]=$row;
                }
            } else {
                $outPut['error']=$this->errorDB($dblink);
            }
            $this->Close_Con_DB($dblink);
        } else {
            $outPut['error']='No hay conexión';
        }
        return $outPut;
    }
```

**Query Executed:** *(sorry but the database is in Spanish XD)*

```
SELECT 
Master_Producto.*, 
Producto_Estructura.*,
Producto_Proveedor.*,
Producto_Precio.*,
FROM Master_Producto
LEFT JOIN(SELECT * FROM Producto_Estructura) AS Producto_Estructura ON ( Master_Producto.Prod_Code = Producto_Estructura.Prod_Code AND Master_Producto.Prod_PF = Producto_Estructura.Prod_PF)
LEFT JOIN(SELECT * FROM Producto_Proveedor) AS Producto_Proveedor ON ( Master_Producto.Prod_Code = Producto_Proveedor.Prod_Code AND Master_Producto.Prod_PF = Producto_Proveedor.Prod_PF)
LEFT JOIN(SELECT * FROM Producto_Precio ORDER BY Prod_DateUpd DESC) AS Producto_Precio ON ( Master_Producto.Prod_Code = Producto_Precio.Prod_Code AND Master_Producto.Prod_PF = Producto_Precio.Prod_PF)
```

***Second Doubt***

***the strange thing is that PHPmyadmin if it shows me the complete results ... it displays 1 section for each table ... but I can't do it myself in php. This example is the result of executing the same query tube that cropping it in images so that they appreciate the repetition of columns.***

[image]

Comment: I am currently seeking to answer the second Doubt.

Comment: 300 columns is seriously abnormal.  You will have to do the aliasing for your odd query.

Comment: i solve it... and this is not my database design... ok...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no alternative but to create an appropriate solution for the analysis of the result. honestly that the database has a bad design is not an excuse not to give it a solution ... and the best solution is to work with the data in the backend:

```php
    // Conection to database
    function Open_Con_PDO($dbUsing){
        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_PRE . $dbUsing, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASS);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $conn->exec("set names utf8");
            return $conn;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die( $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    // function to excute the query
    function BDquery2($dbquery, $dbUsing) {
       $dblink = $this->Open_Con_PDO($dbUsing);
       $resultset = $dblink->prepare($dbquery);
       $resultset->execute();
       $outPut=[];
       $rowc =0;
       while ($row = $resultset->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
            $outPut[$rowc]=[];
            foreach($row as $key => $value){
                $outPut[$rowc][$key]=[
                    'ColumnName'=>$resultset->getColumnMeta($key)['name'],
                    'value'=>$value
                ];
            }
            $rowc++;
       }
       return $outPut;
    }

    // USage Example:
    $dbquery = "SELECT 
Master_Producto.*, 
Producto_Estructura.*,
Producto_Proveedor.*,
Producto_Precio.*,
FROM Master_Producto
LEFT JOIN(SELECT * FROM Producto_Estructura) AS Producto_Estructura ON ( Master_Producto.Prod_Code = Producto_Estructura.Prod_Code AND Master_Producto.Prod_PF = Producto_Estructura.Prod_PF)
LEFT JOIN(SELECT * FROM Producto_Proveedor) AS Producto_Proveedor ON ( Master_Producto.Prod_Code = Producto_Proveedor.Prod_Code AND Master_Producto.Prod_PF = Producto_Proveedor.Prod_PF)
LEFT JOIN(SELECT * FROM Producto_Precio ORDER BY Prod_DateUpd DESC) AS Producto_Precio ON ( Master_Producto.Prod_Code = Producto_Precio.Prod_Code AND Master_Producto.Prod_PF = Producto_Precio.Prod_PF)";


    $result = BDquery2($dbquery,'database_name');

    var_dump($result);
```

output example:

```
$result=[
    10=>[
        'ColumnName'='Prod_D_1',
        'value'=21
    ],
    ...
    24=>[
        'ColumnName'='Prod_D_1',
        'value'=1
    ],
];
```

There is nothing written in pieda the function that obtains the data offers a structure that may not solve other complex scenarios but it is a base for those who find this post to have a starting point if they face the duplication / collision of column names.